# import not found Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm trying to import OrbitControls to my program but it doesn't work. I'm running the program using http-server in Node.js:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>OBJ ARQ</title>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from '/js/three.module.js';
        import {OrbitControls} from "/js/OrbitControls.js";
    </script>
</html>
```

This is my folder structure on my machine. The "OrbitControls.js" file is inside the "js" folder. Is there a Syntax error?

[image: Folder structure]

The Error I get is:

```
SyntaxError: import not found: OrbitControls
```

Comment: where does the OrbitControls.js file come from? Does it contain an `export`-statement?  (just look at the last line of the file). If not, you got the wrong file and need to take the one from the examples/*jsm* directory: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/controls

Comment: That's it, thank you very much. I had the wrong file.